# XSL - Show an image stored as a blob

Tags: sql-server, xslt, blob, xsl-fo

Originally, I had a table in SQL Server with a field that contained an URL to a picture.

I created an XSL template to customize the info window of that table in ArcMap. To show that image I only had to do this:

```
<xsl:variable name="pic" select="$theField[FieldName='PIC']/FieldValue"/>
<img border="0" src="{$pic}" width="200"/>
```

Now, the picture is stored as a blob in the database. A `VARBINARY` field.

How can I set the `<img>` tag from a blob source?

I've been reading several answers for similar issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37654452/foinstream-foreign-object-does-not-show-the-image-properly) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701036/stream-a-blob-image-through-a-xml-xslt-process), but they don't fit my case or I'm being incapable of doing it.

Is even possible to accomplish it with just an XSL template?

I have already tried this (and similar variations):

```
<fo:instream-foreign-object content-type="image/png">
    <xsl:variable name="pic" select="$theField[FieldName='PIC']/FieldValue"/>
    <img border="0" src="{$pic}" width="200"/>
</fo:instream-foreign-object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is in a format that FOP supports (likely) *and* you can convert the image to Base64 (?) *and* FOP can use the `data:` scheme to inline the image data in the `src` property value (I can't find anything to say that it can or cannot) *then* you would be able to do something like:

```
<fo:external-graphic
src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAMAAABEpIrGAAAAB
3RJTUUH1AIFCDIuN9BfzQAAAAlw ... ="/>
```

Otherwise, you may have to come up with a URL to put in the `src` property value so that FOP can access the image directly from the database.

Comment: Thanks!

Your answer took me to the right path. After several tests, I have dropped FOP and now I use:

'<img border="0" src="data:image/png;base64,{$pic}" width="200"/>'

Comment: It's good that it's working for you.  What are you using now instead of FOP?

Comment: FWIW, AH Formatter supports the `data:` scheme: https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf65/ahf-gra.html

Comment: I created the first binary with FME and I thought it was Base64, but it seems it wasn't. I have enconded it to Binary64 and store it in a `VARCHAR`in the database. In my XSL template I haven't used FOP or anything similar, just the `<img>` tag with the `src` parameter as you have posted. It's working in ArcMap, so thanks!!