# OutofMemoryException on LOH

Tags: c#, out-of-memory

I've a simple c# application which tries to read and write a single row to SQL Server Database.
That row contains an Image field that I fill with 100 MB or little greater than.

Every time I get System.OutOfMemoryException.

So, instead to read and write the array bytes in a single instruction, I would like do that in more than one instruction by appending all together.

Is it possibile accomplish that through SqlDataAdapter?

Comment: Are you trying to write a single 100MB blob to the database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Memory effective way to read BLOB data in C#/SQL 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487808/memory-effective-way-to-read-blob-data-in-c-sql-2005)

Comment: why not just use file system :)

Comment: LOH OOM could be raised by memory fragmentation,  you can try compact LOH with .net 4.5